# "Already listening" when invoking an RPC call

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, interop, rpc

I use Microsoft RPC for interprocess communications. I have an interface with a set of methods accepting a byte pipe as an "in" parameter (IDL description):

```
[
    uuid(ActualGuidHere), 
    version(1.0), 
    pointer_default(unique)
]

interface IMyInterface
{
    //other irrelevant methods here
    error_status_t rpcDoAction( [in] pipe byte params );
    //more irrelevant methods here
}
```

every once in a while when I invoke such methods on a client side through a client stub generated by MIDL and delegated to NdrClientCall2(), it doesn't reach the server side, but NdrClientCall2() returns RPC_S_ALREADY_LISTENING ("The server is already listening") which is really confusing.

I added logging into the functions used for push/pull operations during transfer - they are not ever called for any of the calls that fail this way. This implies that the transmission is not even started.

I never encounter such behaviour when calling methods that don't have pipes as parameters.

What might be the reason and the workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation seems quite minimal - I don't think there is a huge user community for *direct* use of the RPC APIs - but my guess is that in order to set up the pipe parameter, it is necessary for RPC to internally call `RpcServerListen`. Only one call to that API is able to block at a time.

The fact that you see the problem only occasionally suggests that it is time-related, so is it possible that you are making two such calls on different threads and sometimes they will be simultaneous?

Either that or there is a timing-related bug in the RPC library's implementation and you will have to work around it by retrying the call (that may be an effective workaround in any case).

Comment: After carefully considering all the facts we had we raised an incident with Microsoft support and... it is really a bug in MS RPC runtime that can be worked around quite easily: http://blogs.msdn.com/alejacma/archive/2009/05/27/ndrclientcall2-fails-with-rpc-s-already-listening-when-using-pipes-over-ncalrpc.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I think this should not be treated as a problem. See [PRB: CoCreateInstance Fails in RPC Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa373942(VS.85).aspx)

View this one too : [How To Register Multiple RPC Server Interfaces](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa373944(VS.85).aspx)

[UPDATE]
Maybe there is problem in the release of memory. See examples of implementation of [PIPE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa374367(VS.85).aspx) and check your code.
[Implementing Input Pipes on the Client](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa373942(VS.85).aspx)
[Implementing Output Pipes on the Client](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa373944(VS.85).aspx)
[Implementing Input Pipes on the Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa373943(VS.85).aspx)
[Implementing Output Pipes on the Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa373945(VS.85).aspx)

Good luck.

Comment: This means we have a serious problem... In the example with CoCreateInstance() the whole thing works, just error indication is incorrect. In our case the RPC call doesn't even get started - no pipe operations are performed.

Comment: place some piece of you IDL for better understanding.

Comment: Added the interface definition. Nothing special.